# Removing quotes from returned CSV file

Tags: javascript

I am a beginner coder and looking to work with csv data retrieved using an api call and then splitting it into arrays.
I want to chart the data so in order to plot it I need to remove the double quotes around the csv data. 
It comes in like this:

"2020-02-04","0.7531"

"2020-02-05","0.7525"

I need it to look like this:

2020-02-04,0.7531

2020-02-05,0.7525

This is the code. I tried playing around with 
var myStr = myStr.replace(/"/g, ''); 
in javasript but I can't seem to get it to work.

```
  async function getData() {
    // const response = await fetch('testdata.csv');
    var response = await fetch('xxxxxxx.csv');
    var data = await response.text();

    var years = [];
    var temps = [];
    var rows = data.split('\n').slice(9);
    rows.forEach(row => {
      var cols = row.split(",");
      years.push(cols[0]);
      temps.push(1 + parseFloat(cols[1]));
    });
    console.log (years, temps );
    return { years, temps };
```

Comment: Use `.slice(1, -1)` like `years.push(cols[0].slice(1, -1));` and `temps.push(parseFloat(cols[1].slice(1, -1)));`

Comment: Replacing should work, you just left out a double-quote: `.replace(/"/g, "")`. try: "dasdasdas\"dasdas".replace(/"/g, "")

Comment: Thanks guys, being a beginner I found this line the easiest to place and it seems to work:
data = data.replace(/"/g, ""); 
There are still line breaks at the end though so empty data points. Is there a way to use a similar style code to get rid of those as well? I tried this but it seems to get rid of all. 
data = data.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm,"");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(cols[0]).replace(/"/g, "") before years.push(cols[0]) statement will do, if you are only having problem with double quotes.

Answer (score 1):

Don't try to write your own CSV parser.

If your data is simple, then you are wasting your time by reinventing the wheel.

If your data gets marginally complex, then you'll trip over the edge cases in the CSV data format design.

Pick an existing parser such as [Papa Parse](https://www.papaparse.com/) and use it instead. It knows how to deal with quotes around data (and quotes in the middle of data, and new lines etc etc etc).

```
const data = await response.text();
const results = Papa.parse(data);
const rows = results.data;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are sure the quotes are always there you can get rid of them using [substring](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substring.asp)

```
let withoutQuotes = cols[i].substring(1, cols[i].length - 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the replace function a little bit wrong. This should work for you:

```
a = '"2020-02-04","0.7531"';
a= a.replace(/"/g, "");
```

The replace function has two arguments. The first argument '/"/g' specifies a [Regular Expression](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/javascript/javascript_regexp_object.htm). Everything that you put between the two slahes is searched for (in this case only "). The 'g' after the second slash symbolizes that they should not stop after the first match they found but look for all matches in the string.

The second argument specifies what you want all matches to be replaced with. In this case, that is nothing -> ""  . But you could also go for a space for example (" ").

Good luck with your coding experience!

Comment: In the end I was able to get this line to work. 
data = data.replace(/"/g,"");
Thanks for the suggestions though. It's a lot to learn.
I would still like to remove the empty line breaks at the end of the csv file though. Any suggestions?? Trying this but it seems to only remove one of the lines not the two that are there.
if(rows[rows.length-1] ===''){
    rows.pop()
}

Comment: Almost there I would say. For now you check whether the last row of your array is empty and if it is empty you remove it. Logically, this will only remove one row at max! You could copy that line e.g. 5 times then it would remove up to 5 empty rows at the end but that would be really bad coding practice. Replacing "if" with "while" should fix your problem. For as long as the last line is empty, you want to remove it and check again.